# Implementing typeahead in angularjs material design text input

Tags: angularjs, typeahead, material-design

How can I implement typeahead like functionality (autosuggestion), keeping the nice "material design" in AngularJS (https://material.angularjs.org)

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: in the new version, it is already implemented.

Answer (score 1):

You cans Autocomplete field.

[image]

The documentation is at
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using Autocomplete in Angular Material; however it is not immediately obvious from the documentation.

The [demo](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.autocomplete) only matches characters at the beginning of the result due to specifying the [caret flag](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdHighlightText), ie: `md-highlight-flags="^i"`

To allow autocomplete to find any matching characters you should use the global flag, ie: `md-highlight-flags="gi"`

You will also need to change the `state.value.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) === 0` line in the filterFn function to `state.value.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) !== -1`

Check this codepen for a working example:
http://codepen.io/DevVersion/pen/KrOYoG

Answer (score -1):

You can refer to following demo link https://material.angularjs.org/1.0.2/demo/autocomplete

Comment: For future reference, link only answers are frowned upon, as the link may die.